# Android tabview icon with background color

Tags: android, background, tabview

I am trying to make a tabview in android that has icon alongwith background. But can't set background of the tab.

java

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, mainActivity.class);   
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator("Main", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_main)).setContent(intent);   
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cameraiconblack"        
          android:state_selected="true" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cameraiconwhite" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"     android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />
```

Then in tab_unselected.xml write

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <solid android:color="#ccc"/>


 </shape>
```

& for tab_selected.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<solid android:color="#ccc"/>


</shape>
```

Now for back ground make layout file for image and textview or whatever u want

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="64dip"    
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/title1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
/>
```

Now change your main tab file like this

put setTabs() method in your oncreate.

```
private void setTabs() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.line);
    intent = new Intent(this, class1.class);
    addTab(1,intent,"tab1");
    intent=new Intent(this,class2.class);
    addTab(2,intent,"tab2");
    intent=new Intent(this,class3.class);
    addTab(3,intent,"tab3");

}
```

Now addTab method

```
private void addTab(int labelId, Intent intent, String tabName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);        

   View tabIndicator =LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title1);
    title.setTextSize(40);
    title.setText(tabName);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aries);


    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

I think i have put all codes required.Now enjoy

Comment: But how to add icon along with it should i have to add  android:drawable="@drawable/tab_icon" under tab_selected.xml and tab_unselected.xml

Comment: You must specify a layout for the image.Then call this image in your class like this      ImageView imageView=(ImageView)tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
  imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.aries); it will set image in background

Answer (score 0):

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;
```

View view_temples= LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_view, null);

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("main").setIndicator(view_temples.findViewById(R.id.your_image_layout_temple))
        .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

Comment: ---tab_view.xml----

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/your_image_layout_temple" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/yourimage_view"
  android:src="@drawable/your_selector"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: and -----your_selector.xml------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_image" /> <!--  pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/focused_image" />   <!-- focused -->
     <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image" /><!-- selected -->  
        
         <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_image" />  <!-- default -->
 </selector>